# How to disable discord.py logger?

Tags: python, logging, bots, discord.py

So I've tried to add some logger to my discord bot, to see logs in file not just in console, cause obviously it's irritating when I reset app and find out that I have to check logs that I've already destroyed, I set it up like this:

```
logging.basicConfig(filename='CoronaLog.log', level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(message)s')
```

And learned the hard way that discord.py library has its own logger installed so now my logs look like one big mess, is there any way to disable discord.py's logging, or at least output it to another file?

EDIT: I've tried creating two loggers, so it would look like this:

```
logging.basicConfig(filename='discord.log', level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(message)s')

nonDiscordLog = logging.getLogger('discord')
handler = logging.FileHandler(filename='CoronaLog.log', encoding='utf-8', mode='w')
handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(levelname)s %(asctime)s:%(name)s: %(message)s'))
nonDiscordLog.addHandler(handler)
```

So the discord log, would be logged as the basic config says to `discord.log` file and, when executed like this:

```
nonDiscordLog.info("execution took %s seconds \n" % (time.time() - startTime))
```

would log into `CoronaLog.log` file, although it didn't really change anything

Answer (score 4):

`discord.py` is in this regard terribly unintuitive for everyone but beginners, anyway after confronting the docs you can find out that this behavior can be avoided with:

```
import discord

client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.all())

# Your regular code here

client.run(__YOURTOKEN__, log_handler=None)
```

Of course, you can supplement your own logger instead of `None` but to answer your question exactly, this is how you can disable `discord.py`'s logging.

There's actually a bit more that you can do with the default logging, and you can read all about it on
[the official docs](https://discord.py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.run)

Comment: Just to be clear, I'm aware that you're propably not looking for the solution after 2 years, so this answer is mostly for all the people in the  future with the same problem

Answer (score 1):

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/logging.html says:
"discord.py logs errors and debug information via the logging python module. It is strongly recommended that the logging module is configured, as no errors or warnings will be output if it is not set up. Configuration of the logging module can be as simple as:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
```

Placed at the start of the application. This will output the logs from discord as well as other libraries that use the logging module directly to the console."
Maybe try configuring logging a different way? Because when starting logging, it appears to initialize discord.py's llogging. maybe try

```
import logging
# Setup logging...
import discord
```

Maybe if you import it afterwords, it won't set it up.

Comment: Effect is the same in both configurations